Does the ability to use fossil fuels require a Designer
I was thinking about my car today and what would happen if it's been too long since I changed the air filter. Probably it would get less and less air as the filter clogged up and so it would function as if I was at a higher altitude. The engine would likely adjust by making the fuel air mixture more lean, so power would drop off and it might overheat. Airplane engines of course encounter this routinely. The operating envelope would pinch off with the airflow.
Then I thought of how remarkable that there is enough oxygen in the atmosphere that fossil fuel vehicles work at all! (And that we are able to be conscious, but I won't digress in to that.) The early Earth did not have much or any oxygen in the atmosphere at all. Doesn't this development cry out for an explanation?
I certainly wonder about it, but that's just because it is April Fools!!!

We could wonder about mitochondria too. What a bizarre idea!

“Huh - I guess that’s what they say about time and stuff.” - Scott Rowe

@JuliusHamilton it is all very perplexing.

If every "how remarkable that there is" required a designer we'd still be attributing rainbows, celestial motions and animal adaptations to the divine. It is a lazy way to 'explain' phenomena, appealing to design should be the last resort after searching long and hard for more informative explanations. Conditions on Earth evolved from what they initially were under perfectly natural causes. And there are many planetary systems out there, so plenty of opportunities for such favorable initial conditions to emerge at least once without any design.

@AlbertusMagnus "does scientific knowledge really kill your ability to marvel at nature" - to the contrary! If this world was made by an all powerful god, then everything in it becomes almost trivial. After all, god can do whatever she wants, right? How easy for a god to make a rainbow, then? I think it's truly much more amazing that all this stuff is happening naturally.

One can argue for this from the point of view of Final Anthropic Principle as well.
Indeed, why do we have enough ready-for-burning fuel in Earth's crust if the atmosphere is full with a strong oxydizer? Is not this improbable? What about electricity? Is not it just magic that electricity, a form of pure energy can be easily stored and transmitted and can do lots of things, from mechanical motion to lighting, heating and computing?

@Anixx ESP and Telekinesis would have been nice. Who left that out of the spec?

You could be right. Some years ago, the main lake on my estate developed a leak and drained completely. I had to pay a crack team of expert 'puddlers' to spend almost three months treading the artificial clay lining by hand, or, rather, by foot, to restore its integrity. The silver lining was that when they found the cause of the breach in the clay lining, it was a fossilised bone, which, on further excavation, proved to be just part of an entire skeleton of a previously unknown dinosaur remarkably like  Tyrannosaurus Rex but much larger. Fearing the inevitable delay if the idiots at the British Museum heard about it, I swore the puddlers to secrecy and had them cut-up the entire skeleton into foot long pieces with chainsaws. That winter, I burned the lot in the boiler of the main house, saving myself such an absolute fortune in coal that it more than paid the exorbitant cost of the puddling. If that's not evidence of divine intention, I don't know what is.

In High School I called gasoline "dinosaur blood". We all thought that it would run out long before this. Good design, I guess.

It's called the Goldilocks principle of design.
There is only one rule. Everything has to be "just right".
The leading proponent was legendary designer and philosopher: Rube Goldberg. Goldberg's simple yet complex designs illustrate that complexity is proportional to achieving "just rightness" proving that if it's "just right" then it was designed.

@ScottRowe I'm a proud April fool. ;-)

We all have our bears to cross!
